# Do subscribers work on a FIFO queue?

Tags: ros, queue, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do the queues used in [ros::Subscriber](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/message_filters/html/c++/classmessage__filters_1_1Subscriber.html) behave like FIFO queues?

In particular, if I use a [message_filters::Synchronizer](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/message_filters/html/c++/classmessage__filters_1_1Synchronizer.html) that, in approximately equal time increments, invokes a callback function for a subscribed topic with queue size 1000. Will the queue items (passed to the callback) be processed in FIFO order?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10539/do-subscribers-work-on-a-fifo-queue?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-07-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-07-09**:
Empirical evidence says: yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes they are FIFO on order of receipt.  The closed documentation I'm aware of is in the [roscpp overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Queueing_and_Lazy_Deserialization)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3